# Adding default active state to hover sliding accordion li

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using an horizontal sliding accordion and I have each element become active(expand) on hover, but in a dormant state the initial active element should expand, instead of all the LIs collapsing.

**Please see example** http://jsfiddle.net/WT8Tg/

### **HTML**

```
        <ul class="accordion" id="accordion">
            <li class="bg1">
                <div class="heading">Guler</div>
                <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                <div class="description">
                    <h2>Guler</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                        ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                        nulla pariatur.</p>
                    <a href="#">more &rarr;</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="bg2">
                <div class="heading">Phillips</div>
                <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                <div class="description">
                    <h2>Phillips</h2>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
                        accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa
                        quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
                        dicta sunt explicabo. </p>
                    <a href="#">more &rarr;</a>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li class="bg3">
                <div class="heading">Diamanti</div>
                <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                <div class="description">
                    <h2>Diamanti</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
                        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
                        ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
                        reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                        nulla pariatur.</p>
                    <a href="#">more &rarr;</a>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li class="bg4 bleft active">
                <div class="heading">Meiklejohn</div>
                <div class="bgDescription"></div>
                <div class="description">
                    <h2>Meiklejohn</h2>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
                        accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa
                        quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae
                        dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas
                        sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni
                        dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
                    <a href="#">more &rarr;</a>
                </div>

            </li>
        </ul>
```

### **CSS**

```
    ul.accordion > li.active {
            width:480px;
    }

    ul.accordion{
        list-style:none;   
        position:absolute;
        right:80px;
        top:0px;
        font-family: Cambria, serif;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 1.5em;
    }
    ul.accordion li{
        float:right;
        width:115px;
        height:480px;
        display:block;
        border-right:2px solid #fff;
        border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
        background-color:#fff;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center center;
        position:relative;
        overflow:hidden;
        cursor:pointer;
        -moz-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
        -webkit-box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
        box-shadow:1px 3px 15px #555;
    }




    ul.accordion li.bg1{
        background-image:url(../images/1.jpg);
    }
    ul.accordion li.bg2{
        background-image:url(../images/2.jpg);
    }
    ul.accordion li.bg3{
        background-image:url(../images/3.jpg);
    }
    ul.accordion li.bg4{
        background-image:url(../images/4.jpg);
    }
    ul.accordion li.bleft{
        border-left:2px solid #fff;
    }
    ul.accordion li .heading{
        background-color:#fff;
        padding:10px;
        margin-top:60px;
        opacity:0.9;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-style:normal;
        font-weight:bold;
        letter-spacing:1px;
        font-size:14px;
        color:#444;
        text-align:center;
        text-shadow:-1px -1px 1px #ccc;
    }
    ul.accordion li .description{
        position:absolute;
        width:480px;
        height:175px;
        bottom:0px;
        left:0px;
        display:none;
    }
    ul.accordion li .description h2{
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-style:normal;
        font-weight:bold;
        letter-spacing:1px;
        font-size:45px;
        color:#444;
        text-align:left;
        margin:0px 0px 15px 20px;
        text-shadow:-1px -1px 1px #ccc;
    }
    ul.accordion li .description p{
        line-height:14px;
        margin:10px 22px;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: 1.6em;
    }
    ul.accordion li .description a{
        position:absolute;
        bottom:5px;
        left:20px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-style:normal;
        font-size:11px;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#888;
    }
    ul.accordion li .description a:hover{
        color:#333;
        text-decoration:underline;
    }

    ul.accordion li .bgDescription{
        background:transparent url(../images/bgDescription.png) repeat-x top left;
        height:340px;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0px;
        left:0px;
        width:100%;
        display:none;
    }
```

### **JQuery**

```
         $(function() {
            $('#accordion > li').hover(
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.stop().animate({'width':'480px'},500);
                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut();
                    $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideDown(500);
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                },
                function () {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    $this.stop().animate({'width':'115px'},1000);
                    $('.heading',$this).stop(true,true).fadeIn();
                    $('.description',$this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(500);
                    $('.bgDescription',$this).stop(true,true).slideUp(700);
                }
            );

            $(function() {      
                $('#accordion').on('click', 'li', function() {  
                    $('.accordion li.active').removeClass('active'); //Remove any "active" class  
                    $('li', this).addClass('active'); //Add "active" class to selected tab  


                    //Commented since it is not available
                    //$(activeTab).show(); //Fade in the active content  
                    return false;  
                }); 
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a few rules to accommodate for that behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/WT8Tg/3/

I added this on hover:

```
$('li').stop().animate({'width':'115px'},1000);
```

I added this when hover is over:

```
$('.bg4').stop().animate({'width':'480px'},500);
```

I highly recommend using classes to assign the widths instead of hardcoding it within the Javascript. You can then just animate the removal/adding of classes.

Comment: Thank you Aephilea! And I agree, classes are a lot more convenient. This was plugin I downloaded and was aiming to modify it. Once I view the js I realized the widths are hard coded with js.

Comment: Also, is it possible to make width parameters fixed? instead of the accordion expanding and contracting. please see example: http://www.egrappler.com/raccordion/demo1.htm